# .Net Core - IMemoryCache - Eventual Expiry using Sliding Timespan

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a web-api that is fetching information from a GET request, I am planning to cache the response using IMemoryCache to prevent duplicate HTTP requests in my application.

However, the data from the GET request will change every hour, and when changed will invalidate the cached response. which means the cache item needs to be refreshed every hour, and I know that if I use sliding refresh then there is a risk that this won't happen and there will be a stale cached item.

I am looking for help to create a solution that will let's say, monitor cache items and remove those that haven't been referenced in a certain amount of time or when it's time to update the cached value (refresh).

Can anybody help with this?

Comment: which means you want set policy to slide refresh ?

Comment: Let me look into that, is it possible to set a policy with a sliding refresh that contains an absolute expiry time?

Comment: Got it, you can set both sliding and expiration

Comment: I don't know,  but I think you can inherit from response cache attribute to customize it. just like check how many time this api called(you can store it anywhere ) then set it policy via if and else or whatever

Comment: See my answer, both sliding and absolute can be set.

Comment: I saw it, you're right. good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out how to do this.

It is possible to set the AbsoluteExpiration property to be 1 hour from now and set a SlidingExpiration for a custom time period.

The SlidingExpiration property description says:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets how long a cache entry can be inactive (e.g. not accessed) before it will be removed.
/// This will not extend the entry lifetime beyond the absolute expiration (if set).
/// </summary>
TimeSpan? SlidingExpiration { get; set; }
```